# Error#1009 Cannot access a null object when using URLRequest to load images

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am trying to load a few images from the server using URLRequest, it traces all the URL correctly but the CurrentTarget is null and it gives the error#1009 Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference. I am not sure why.

The steps:

1. Sends out text to database to retrieve the image urls via URLRequest
2. the text are parsed through as JSON, and that is put into an array
3. The array that contains the images' URL are loaded

At the moment it loads the images URL and then calls the error null for the `e.currentTarget`.

Please give me some advice, thanks.

Code:

```
SrSend = new URLRequest("http://testurl/requestimage.php");
SrSend.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
Arvariables = new URLVariables;
SrSend.data = Arvariables;
SaLoader = new URLLoader();
SaLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;

Arvariables.data1 = somedata[0];

SaLoader.load(SrSend);
SaLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, Asandler);

function imagesLoaded():void
{
    removeChild(loader);
    removeChild(blackBox1);
    removeChild(sss);
    var currentY2:int = 100;
    for(var i:uint = 0; i < loadedImages.length; i++)
    {
        trace('add image with index', i);


        holder[i] = new Sprite();
        loadedImages[i].y = currentY2;
        currentY2 += loadedImages[i].height + 10;
        holder[i].addChild(loadedImages[i]);


        holder[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.DOUBLE_CLICK, gotoscene);
        holder.mouseChildren = true; // ignore children mouseEvents NOT TRUE - should be false!
        holder.mouseEnabled = true; // true by default
        holder.useHandCursor = true; // add hand cursor on mouse over
        holder.buttonMode = true; // ACTUALLY this will add the cursor

        _contentHolder.addChild(holder[i]);
    }
}

function loadImage():void
{
    trace(myArray);

    for(var i:int = 0; i < myArray.length; i++)
    {

        if(myArray[i])
        {
            loader11 = new Loader();
            loader11.load(new URLRequest("http://www.testurl/" + myArray[i]));
            loader11.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onImageLoaded);
        }
    }
}

trace(myArray);

function searchVOs(pic:String)
{
    this.pic = pic;
}

function Asandler(event:Event):void
{
    trace(event.target.data);
    // retrieve data from php call
    var resultString:String = event.target.data;

    trace(event.target.data);

    // parse result string as json object and cast it to array
    var resultArray:Array = JSON.parse(resultString) as Array;

    var len:int = resultArray.length;

    trace(resultString);

    // create vector of SearchVO
    var searchVOs:Vector.<Listingdetailinfo> = new Vector.<Listingdetailinfo>();


    // get the length of the result set
    var i:int;
    for(i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        searchVOs[i] = new Listingdetailinfo();
        searchVOs[i].pic = resultArray[i].pic;

        myArray.push(searchVOs[i].pic);
    }
}

function onImageLoaded(e:Event):void
{
    var currentY1 = 100;
    e.currentTarget.loader.content.width = stage.stageWidth * 0.8;
    e.currentTarget.loader.content.scaleY = e.currentTarget.loader.content.scaleX;
    e.currentTarget.loader.content.y += currentY1;

    loadedImages.push(e.target.content as Bitmap);

    trace(loadedImages);

    trace(somedata);
    if(loadedImages.length == myArray.length)
    {
        imagesLoaded();
    }
}

function stopload(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    loader11.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onImageLoaded);
    removeChild(loader);
    removeChild(blackBox1);
    removeChild(sss);
}
```

Edit:

```
e.currentTarget.loader.content.width =
                     stage.stageWidth*0.8;

 e.currentTarget.loader.content.width =100;
```

Comment: I think that this is Stage which is null in that line of code. You should put breakpoint exactly at that line, debug the app and find out what is null.

Comment: Hi, i tried to put a break point there, and also tried to just set an exact width for the currentTarget content.width.When i set an exact width to the currentTarget, it just continuously looping. I am not sure why. Seems like it isnt loading the content, but just non stop looping the Vector Part.

Comment: You put the breakpoint and what? Did you find out what object is null? Also, there is no Vector in that method. Not sure what are you trying to explain. I think you should read some information on how to debug actionscript 3 code.

Comment: Hi, i put the breakpoint on that exact line,and i split the line into 2, it calls error on the line stage.stageWidth*0.8; i put it in the Edit above. So i tried again trying to set the width as an exact value. Then when the width is an exact value, it goes into an infinite loop of loading the JSON.

Comment: I am not sure why is it going in an infinite loop of loading the JSON (the Asandler) which is the handler oncomplete from the eventlistener.

Comment: Did you put your code into some frame? The movie clip may just enter this frame again and again, thus your code is called multiple times